# How to change dynamically the path for saving a bunch of csv files

Tags: excel, vba, csv

Every week, I use different path for saving a bunch of csv files by date of a week. E.g. We are running week N46 (Calendar company) and I will create one csv file for Monday, another for Tuesday and so on. I will save them using a path `c:\weekN46\csvFiles` AND, next week I will do similar operation but will be `c:\weekN47\csvFiles` and so. I wish to use VBA Excel code for saving all csv files in the regarding folder week.

Comment: Have a lookup table containing your company calendar that maps dates to company weeks then in your vba do a lookup against this to get the value to use in your variable. Then see here: https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/forum/help-forums/excel-general/143135-vba-macro-to-save-file-in-a-variable-date-folder-and-name-file   Links gives examples of creating directory if doesn't already exist.

Comment: Thank you very much for your value help. Have a nice day and weekend!

Answer (score 0):

These two functions will help you to create a folder with current week it it does not exists, You can also use them to get the current week folder name.

Below function to return the current week folder name , You can also  use to get the folder name to save the file

```
Function SaveAddreess() As String

    Dim WeekNumber As String
    Dim WeekFolder  As String

    WeekNumber = CStr(Format(Now, "ww"))
    WeekFolder = "WeekN" & WeekNumber
    SaveAddreess = "c:\" & WeekFolder & Application.PathSeparator

End Function
```

So if you want to save abc.csv to this week then you can generate the current week folder name and save it to that path.

Below Code is to check if this week folder exists or not if it does it will do nothing,if it does not, it will create one.

```
Function CreateThisWeekFolder()

    Dim fs As Object
    Dim fol As Object
    Dim thisweekFolder As String

    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    thisweekFolder = SaveAddreess


    If fs.FolderExists(thisweekFolder) Then
            'DO NOTHING
    Else
            fs.CreateFolder (thisweekFolder)
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: Great! Thank you, pankajkushwaha

Comment: Great! Thank you very much for your value help.